# I want to use pytest to test if a ValueError raises inside the constructor of a class

Tags: python, constructor, pytest

There is a class:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, bar: int) -> None:
        self.bar = bar
        if self.bar < 0:
            raise ValueError("bar must be positive.")
    
   ...
```

I want to test if the ValueError raises with pytest, but I'm not familiar with it so I'm not sure how to write the code.

```
import pytest

class TestFoo:
```

I can't write the next line.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use [`pytest.raises`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/assert.html#assertions-about-expected-exceptions) to see whether a given block raises a given exception:

```
def test_foo_raises_when_instantiating():
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        Foo(-1)
```